# Mouse/keyboard product, replaced twice, all have issues

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I bought a mouse and keyboard bundle from Amazon a couple of months ago.

- Within a week of use, the mouse button stopped working.
- Requested a replacement from Amazon, which I received
- Within a week, the cursor of the replacement mouse stopped moving, so I sent it back and requested a refund.
- I had a look in my local computer store and saw the same product for sale again. Stupidly, I decided to give it a third try.
- After less than a month of use, the a couple of columns of keys on the keyboard, namely `Page Up`, `Page Down` and `*`, `9`, `6`, `3`, `.` on the number intermittently stop functioning (i.e. They sometimes work fine for a while but they quite often stop working)
- I took the product back to my local shop to request a refund but they refused to refund the item as they were unable to reproduce the problem.

I've since tried the keyboard in different USB ports, but still experience the same issue, no matter where it's placed.

Is there a chance that there's a hardware failure within my computer/motherboard causing my mouse/keyboard products to fail? If so, what might the issue be?

My old mouse/keyboard seem to work fine in my computer and I've unfortunately not had the chance to test my keyboard/mouse in another machine.

Cheers!

Comment: "not had the chance to test my keyboard/mouse in another machine" would answer your question if you did. It sounds like a crap mouse and keyboard set to me.

Comment: Say I do test them out on another machine and it turns out they work fine, then there's obviously something up with my machine. Given the nature of the 3 separate issues I've had, do you know (Or could you hazard a guess at) which of component(s) in my machine could be failing?

Comment: I have never seen or heard of what you suggest, a pc damaging usb devices. So that leaves the second line in my comment above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again @Moab. However, I've just had the chance to test my keyboard out at work and it's worked without any sign of fault the whole day. This leads me to believe that something is wrong with my computer. I don't suppose you know which components I could look at first? Perhaps this is the wrong forum to ask such a question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well this is a weird one, I suppose the psu that supplies the 5 volts to the motherboard could be putting out too much voltage but that's a stretch.